# Does the guitar's bridge affect the tone?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, bridge

Does changing my bridge affect my guitar's tone? And will it make palm mutes sound good? I want to change it to a Floyd Rose Ibanez bridge.

Comment: What guitar is this?

Comment: One useful point of view is that *everything* affects tone, just to a greater or lesser degree. That viewpoint allows one to move directly to the next logical questions: How will it affect the tone? How do you feel about that tonal change?

Comment: What guitar is it? What bridge is currently on it? Ibanez has the Edge, which is similar but distinct from the Floyd Rose design. Both require huge routes to hold the springs that balance the strings. If you have a Strat-type guitar, that's likely done. If you have a Les Paul, much less so.

Comment: Please add details. What type of bridge there is already? Is it floyd rose or a fixed bridge. If it's a floyd rose, do you want to install it as a fixed bridge, or drill a cavity, install springs and everything needed for a floyd rose to function?

Answer (score 4):

Bridges with different vibrato systems will vary in terms of tuning stability, range of pitch variation, and response of the bar itself. Bridges also vary in terms of the range of set up they allow, and the ease with which adjustments can be made, strings can be changed, and so on.

However the effect of the bridge on the timbre of the guitar is likely to be very small, assuming it is properly installed and set up. It will be especially small when palm muting, because the damping of the string with the hand reduces the vibrations that are transmitted between the bridge and the part of the string where the pickups are.

The only reason to consider changing a bridge to help your palm muting would be if your current bridge is somehow interfering with your technique. Changing the bridge will probably make little or no noticeable improvement to your tone.

Answer (score 2):

Of course the bridge affects the tone and feel of the guitar. The reason that companies produce bridges from different materials is for their customers who want cheaper instruments. The more pricy bridges, which are made from harder metals that are more difficult to process, offer more resonance and stability. Ideal materials for bridges are stainless steel and bell-brass. The other cheap materials reduce resonance and sustain but are lighter in mass. The quality of the sub-parts of the bridges also offer better tone quality (saddles, springs, screws)...all these transfer vibrations and affect the tone outcome. The more you pay the more you get for those products 99% of the time. Make your choise wisely and make your own limits for what you want.